# Prepared statement like POP PHP Framework

Tags: php

I'm using the POP PHP Framework (http://www.popphp.org/). I'm trying to write a prepared statement to check if an email address already exists or not in the database.

Digging through the manual I can't find any example on how to compare a text string with a result in the database, only numbers. To do that it isn't that hard, just like:

```
$sql->select()->where()->greaterThanOrEqualTo('id', '?');
```

But comparing if an email address exists or not, I can't find the solution for. Below is my incomplete code. Line 6 is where I try to do a comparison. Getting no error because it isn't supported. The mail address exists in the database, so that isn't any problem.

```
// Check if user already exists
$db = Db::factory($this->type, $this->creds);

// Create a prepared statement
$sql = new Sql($db, 'user');
$sql->select()->where()->like('email', '?');

// Prepare the statement, bind the parameters and execute
$db->adapter()->prepare('email', '?');
$db->adapter()->bindParams(array('email' => $post['email']));
$db->adapter()->execute();


print_r($db->adapter()->fetch());


if($db->adapter()->fetch() != false)
{
    $error['userExists'] = "User exists";
    echo "Exists";
}
```

How should I do to get this code complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know POPPHP, but upon inspecting the [API](http://www.popphp.org/docs/api/), it seems what you are looking for is [`Pop\Db\Sql\Predicate::equalTo($column, $value, $combine)`](http://www.popphp.org/docs/api/classes/Pop.Db.Sql.Predicate.html#method_equalTo), e.g.:

```
$sql->select()->where()->equalTo('email', '?');
```

Comment: Thanks for putting me in the right direction. The right code is as follows:    `// Check if user already exists
       $db = Db::factory($this->type, $this->creds);
   
       // Create a prepared statement
       $sql = new Sql($db, 'user');
       $sql->select()->where()->equalTo('email', '?');
       
       echo $sql . '<br />' .  PHP_EOL;
           
       // Prepare the statement, bind the parameters and execute
       $db->adapter()->prepare($sql);
       $db->adapter()->bindParams(array('email' => $post['email']));
       $db->adapter()->execute();`